# Probability of a matrix that is not full rank over the finite field

Tags: probability-theory, finite-fields, random-matrices

The probability of a matrix that is not full rank over the finite field can be calculated as follows. 
\begin{equation}
\Pr\left(\text{rank}(\mathbf{G})<k\right)=\sum_{\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{F}^k_p,\mathbf{w}\neq0}\Pr\left({\mathbf{G}\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0}}\right)=\frac{p^k-1}{p^n}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{G}\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times k}_p$, $k<n$

But I don't know why $\sum_{\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{F}^k_p,\mathbf{w}\neq0}\Pr\left({\mathbf{G}\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0}}\right)=\frac{p^k-1}{p^n}$. Can anybody show me the reason?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

This formula does not seem to be correct. According to the first formula of Section 3 in [1] it should be
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{rank}(G)<k)
= 1 - \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-j}}\right).
$$
E.g., in the special case of random $3 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$ ($n = 3$, $k = 2$ and $p = 2$), this is approximately 0.343, whereas your estimate gives $(2^{n-1}-1)/2^n = 0.375$.

[1] Blake, Ian F., and Chris Studholme. "Properties of random matrices and applications." Unpublished report available at http://www. cs. toronto. edu/~ cvs/coding (2006).

Answer (score 0):

For any fixed $\mathbf{w}$, a uniformly random matrix $\mathbf{G}$ will by definition be such that the vector $\mathbf{G}\mathbf{w}$ is uniformly distributed in $\mathbb{F}_p^n$. Therefore, the probability that it is equal to any fixed vector $\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{F}_p^n$ (and, in particular, to the zero vector $\mathbf{0}_n$ is $1/|\mathbb{F}_p^n|=1/p^n$.

Therefore,
$$
\sum_{\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{F}_p^k\setminus \{\mathbf{0}_k\}} \mathbb{P}\{\mathbf{G}\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0}\} = \sum_{\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{F}_p^k\setminus \{\mathbf{0}_k\}} \frac{1}{p^n} = \frac{p^k-1}{p^n}
$$
as claimed, since $\lvert \mathbb{F}_p^k\setminus \{\mathbf{0}_k\}\rvert = p^k -1$.